# standard time vs miltary time

Tags: android

Im trying to display the current time in a format like 7:45pm instead of 19:45 but i can't seem to find the right format option.

```
Time cTime= new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
cTime.setToNow();
clock.setText(cTime.format("%H:%M"));
```

This seems to display military

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [`Time.format()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#format%28java.lang.String%29), so you can refer to the [C++ `strftime` documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/strftime/) for formatting rules. Your format string should be `%I:%M%P` for 12-hour time.

Comment: thats just about right except it puts a 0 in front  like 08:22pm

Comment: @erik That is a restriction of `Time.format()`, sorry. There is no formatting code which can display the hours in `1-12` format. You could either trim the `0` off the front (using `substring`), or use `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` with `a` - meaning am/pm marker.

Example:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mmaa"); 

try {                   
    String now = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());



} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```